# Error : "Django not found"

Tags: python, django, pydev

I'm working with Eclipse and suddenly I could not use Django anymore.

I tried to make a new project, but an error occurred : "Django not found".

I checked the interpreters like it is said in the forums.
I have uninstalled and installed Django multiple times, change the pythonpath thousands times, I reinstalled pydev, nothing has fixed the issue.

I really don't understand the fact that I was just typing usual code, and suddenly nothing worked again.

Edit : In the python command, I can import django.config but i cannot import Django.config.admin for example.

Comment: 1. Check locate your django folder (Should be in lib/python2/site-packages/django
2. From Eclipse import sys and print sys.path
3. You will find that django's folder is not listed in sys.path
If my assumption is true we can investigate why

Comment: My folder is in C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages

Comment: ['C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\\pysrc', 'C:\\Users\\mabadie_2\\git\\HelatoEclipse', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5\\python35.zip']

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Can you tell me the exact command you execute before you get "Django not found error?"

Comment: I'm using eclipse so i don't use a shell

Comment: but it is like django-admin.py startproject name

Comment: if I use runserver in my project i have ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags'

Comment: yes i did :/ but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found a solution which always works :
uninstall and reinstall everything (python, Django, pydev) whitout using the pip